# Ansible vars file group_vars/"{{ param }}"/vars.yml was not found on the Ansible Controller

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I am trying pass value from jenkins to ansible. However, I am hitting below exception. This only happen for `group_vars`, for hosts, there is no issue.

> ERROR! vars file group_vars/"{{ param }}"/vars.yml was not found on the Ansible Controller

```
- hosts: "{{ param }}"-value
  roles:
    - tests
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/"{{ param  }}"/vars.yml
    - group_vars/all/vars.yml
```

Comment: The files in the `group_vars` folder are picked up automatically.   The hosts in the `{{ param }}` group will have those variables set, and all hosts will have the variables from `group_vars/all/` files.  You either need to change to `hosts: "{{ param }}"`, or change the folder names to addd `-value` to them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try:

```
- hosts: "{{ param }}-value"
  roles:
    - tests
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/{{ param  }}/vars.yml
    - group_vars/all/vars.yml
```

the quotes " are only needed when a value starts with {{.

Comment: let me try ya. what did you mean by " quotes " are only needed when a value starts with {{". param is the value being passed. however will try it now

Comment: can work. for host as well i removed the " mark. wonder when it will be used for " mark

Comment: `key: {{ value }}` won't work. it's not valid a yaml syntax. you have to write `key: "{{ value }}"` but `key: some_{{ value }}` will work.